# Remove Site Collection in SharePoint 2013 using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-2013, csom

I am using the following code to remove the site collection using CSOM:

```
var ctx = new ClientContextWrapper(targetUrl);
var tenant = new Tenant(ctx);
var spoOperation = tenant.RemoveSite(targetUrl);
ctx.Load(spoOperation);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

I am getting this error while execution of ExecuteQuery():

> Error Message:Specified method is not supported.

Comment: I guess targetUrl is the site you try to delete. Therefore how can you instantiate a Tenant object from it, instead of admin tenant url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According some technet statements, it is not possible for on premise.

If you are trying to delete site collection in SharePoint Online here is a nice article with powershell example: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Online-Delete-a-e0aabe36
Do not forget to provide credentials.

Here is another example code: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24050.perform-basic-admin-operations-using-csom-in-sharepoint-online.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The code snipit you show works for me on premise.

Make sure you have installed the April 2014 CU or later in your SharePoint farm.

If you haven't seen this take a look at this link that exlains how to setup the tenate api for on premise development: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2014/06/09/provisioning-site-collections-using-sp-app-model-in-on-premises-with-just-csom.aspx.

Also, I am using version 16.1.3912.1204 of the CSOM APIs. You can download the latest version as a NuGet package in VS2013.  I also recommend that you develop agains the PNP Core library that includes many extensions to the standard CSOM APIs: https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP